# React.js async operation setState returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I use async operations for fetching data from my own API but sometimes react does not wait for operation complete and because of that my state object returns null and causes a null error.

Constructor :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openCase = this.openCase.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      reward: {},
      skins: [],
      caseImg: ""
    };
    this.fillCase = this.fillCase.bind(this);
  }
```

My fetching code :

```
 fillCase = async () => {
    const link = encodeURI("https://localhost:44390/api/getskins");
    const response = await fetch(link);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ skins: data });
  };
```

And I call fillCase before component mounts:

```
componentWillMount(){
this.fillCase();
}
```

What is error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `data` you fetched from the server contains some null values.

Try to print it out while you receive the data, also try filtering it:

```js
fillCase = async () => {
    const link = encodeURI("https://localhost:44390/api/getskins");
    const response = await fetch(link);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ skins: data.filter(d => d) });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if skins is empty array

```
{ this.state.skins.length && this.state.skins.map....}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are few issues here:

1. First of all you do not use CWM for any of your async operations. Use CDM instead.
2. make your CDM async rather than the fillCase() method.

An alternate approach would be to use hooks here. put your data fetching logic in a useEffect hook. It’s just a cleaner and more flexible  way to do the same if you’re familiar with hooks.